# How can I parse JSON output from Facebook php graph api?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, associative-array

I have the this simple code from the example sdk facebook:

```
if ($user) {
try {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}
```

If I print $user_profile the result is the list of friends in this format:

```
[206] => Array
            (
                [name] => name
                [id] => 00000000
            )
```

Is it possible to access to the fields of these arrays?
For example I want to print only the friends' names

Comment: Try $user_profile[206]['friends'] ?

Answer (score 0):

To print only the friends' names, just loop through the main array/object:

```
foreach($user_profile as $k => $friend)
{
    echo $friend['name'].' - '.$user_profile[$key]['id'].'<br/>';
}
```

To access a specific friend:

```
echo $user_profile[11]['name'];
```

This echoes the name of the 11th friend in the array. Combine the two to get the index of a given friend using a function (or method):

```
public function getFriendIndex($name)
{
    foreach($this->user_profile as $index => $friend)
    {
        if ($friend['name'] === $name)
        {//returns the index of $name's friend data
            return $index;
        }
    }
    return null;//friend doesn't exist...
}
```

Comment: @user840718: I've edited my answer, tell me what you see now (also `var_dump($friend)`

Comment: Thanks. I see always the same, 2 empty lines.

Comment: @user840718: what happens if you `var_dump($friend)` inside the loop?

Comment: Well I see everything in this format:
array(207) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(21) "namename" ["id"]=> string(9) "00000000" }

Comment: @user840718: according to your original post, that's what you see when you dump `$user_profile`, I'm asking what you see when you dump `$friend` _inside that loop_